# Compute average distance between vector and its permutations

Tags: matlab, combinations, vectorization, distance

I have a vector, say `x = [1 1.5 2]`. I want to compute the expected distance between that vector and a random permutation of the vector. The assumption is that all permutations are equally likely.

For the example above, the solution should be `4/9`. The first element changes `1/2` on average, the second element changes `1/3` on average, and the last one `1/2`. The average change is therefore `4/9`.

The problem is that this vector has about 50-100 entries. Is there a smart way to compute this expected distance?

Comment: I think for your example, the expected distance is ~1.055. There are 5 permutations of the vector, with distances sqrt(2) (twice), sqrt(2)/2, and 1.225 (also twice), for an average of ~1.055.

Comment: @David: You are talking about Euclidean distance (l2), but the numbers in the question match the [l1-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)

Comment: Yes, I was not precise about the distance measure I am looking for. I actually just want to compute the absolute value of the difference between each two points.

Comment: @Immo: What exactly is your problem implementing this? Everything you need is one or two loops, `abs` and `mean`.

Comment: In that case the answer would be 1.6...

Comment: It's just that I have to repeat this computation many times. I was thinking there was a smart way to use the symmetry of the distances...

Comment: Use `randperm` to sample from the possible permutations, `sum(abs(x-randperm(x)))` to find the distance, and repeat as many times as you want to build an average.

Comment: @David, thanks. I was looking for an exact solution of this problem. I am using randperm right now, but the problem is that it's too computationally expensive.

Comment: There are O(10^64) permutations of a vector with just 50 entries. It is not possible to do this exactly.

Comment: @David, I'm afraid you're right.

Comment: I am now using `mean(mean(abs(bsxfun(@minus,x,x'))))` and this seems to do the trick.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not calculating the average L1 distance between the vector and it's permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am now using `mean(mean(abs(bsxfun(@minus,x,x'))))` and this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

One of the rare cases where `bsxfun` does not provide the fastest solution. If you want to make use of the symmetry, use `pdist`

```
s=sum(pdist(x,'cityblock'))/numel(x).^2*2
```